# Is there a way to get fine grained progress of Elastic Transcoder job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm using `read_job()` API to monitor jobs' progress. This only gives me a very coarse info about the status being one of the: `Submitted | In Progress | Complete | Canceled | Error`.

However, I'd like to show the user a percentage or ETA when in the `In Progress` state. Is there any API which gives such a fine grained progress information?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the "job % complete" is available to us according to the docs:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/elastictranscoder-dg.pdf

The JSON status update only has the "PROGRESSING" state which means very little for a user.

Amazon is aware this is a wanted feature from developers, as seen here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=477076&#477076